# How do I test HTML code written in a text document?

Tags: html

I am using Windows 7 and have written a HTML document and named it with a .html postfix. When I try to run it by opening it with Internet Explorer or Google Chrome, it just shows the code and not a web page.

Comment: does it have a php code in it?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of said code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing the file is actually named `something.html.txt` right now.

Take a look at http://www.howtohaven.com/system/show-file-extensions-in-windows-explorer.shtml

1. Click the Start menu. This is the round icon that is on the bottom left corner of your screen.
2. Type "folder options" (without the quotes). Click the line "Folder Options" that appears at the top of the Start menu.
3. A dialog box with the title "Folder Options" will appear. Click the "View" tab at the top of the window.
4. Click to uncheck the box for "Hide extensions for known file types".
5. Click the "OK" button at the bottom of the dialog box.

After this you can rename it to drop the `.txt`

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. Make sure you are using a plain-text editor.

Markup languages like HTML (and, indeed, most code) need to be written in a plain-text file format. That means the file format must not support fonts, bold/italic/underlined text, inserting non-text elements, or any other formatting.

Do not write markup in software like Microsoft Word or Wordpad. Windows ships with a program called "notepad" designed for creating and editing plain-text. You can use that, or consider a plain-text editor specifically geared towards programming and writing markup such as [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/).

#### 2. Make sure your file is *truly* an HTML file.

Windows 7 introduced a "feature" which, by default, hides the file extension of any file type it recognizes (i.e., has an associated program to launch it). That means if you name a file `index.html`, it may have a hidden extension at the end... making the full filename `index.html.txt`. That's a problem, because the true file extension is now `.txt`.

I recommend you disable this feature permanently, but you can also do so temporarily (just to check if the file has a hidden extension) if you prefer.

In your start menu, search for "Folder Options" and launch it. In the "View" tab, uncheck the box that says "Hide extensions for known file types" and press "OK" or "Apply".

#### 3. Make sure your document is valid.

Browsers do a pretty good job of "fixing" invalid HTML... most of the time. Nevertheless, if your code has certain mistakes, the browser may default to simply displaying the document as a text file.

Try visiting the [W3C Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to automatically check the validity of your document. If anything is wrong, the validator will point it out and suggest ways of fixing it.